# Creating a Folium Map Using Non-numerical data using discrete color

Tags: python, geopandas, streamlit, folium, discrete

I have a non-numerical data which I want to show on folium `map`. I do not find any references how to use a discrete color scheme for non-numerical data on folium.

My sample data is like this

| PROV | MOST_TREES |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | OAK |
| BBB | PINES |

My expectation is a map with yellow for OAK and green for PINES.